# How can I stop the current time and change it with JS/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I am implementing an analogue and digital watch with JS. Got it working with a couple of tutorials but how can I stop the clock and change the hour? Here is the code for digital one:

```
function updateClock() {
  var currentTime = new Date();
  var gtmStatus = 'AM';

  var hours = currentTime.getHours();
  if (hours > 12){
    hours = hours-12;
    gtmStatus = 'PM';
  }

  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
  var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();

  var degree_seconds = -90 + (seconds * 6);
  var degree_minute = -90 + (minutes * 6);
  var degree_hour =  -90 + (hours * 30);
  degree_hour = degree_hour + (0.5 * minutes);

  $('#time').html(hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ' ' + gtmStatus);

setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
updateClock();

}
```

Comment: The header seems to be a bit high-flying ; ). Assigning the interval to a variable, and using that variable as id in [`clearInterval(id)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) will stop the clock though.

Comment: Can you just get the value of #time brother man?

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval(...)` returns a handle/identifier that can be given to `clearInterval(handle)`.

In other words, if you want to *pause* your clock, you need to call `clearInterval(...)` with the previously obtained handle from the last call of `setInterval(...)`. Then, you can start your clock calling `setInterval(...)` again.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getThatThereTime () {
    return $('#time').val();
}
```

Comment: While this answer may be valid, it's better with an explanation. See [Help Center > How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): *Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better*.